# Access CoreData objects created by a private managedObjectContext (created in a background thread)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have this dummy setup (for testing out feasibility). Idea is:
When the game first starts I need to copy a whole bunch of data (stored in `plists`) to the database using CoreData. I want to do this inside a global background queue (so that the UI is still responsive).

That's what I try to do:

```
appDelegate.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (managedObjectContext) in
    GameSetupController.setup(withManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
}
```

I start a `backgroundTask` and call a method on my `GameSetupController`. It looks like this:

```
static func setup(withManagedObjectContext managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let startCoords = Coordinates(atQuadrant: 153, galaxy: 42, system: 3, using: managedObjectContext)
    let startPlanet = Planet(atCoordinates: startCoords, withName: "Planet 1", using: managedObjectContext)
    let startBase = Site(atPlanet: startPlanet, withName: "Name of base", belongingToPlayer: true, using: managedObjectContext)

    // Game is a singleton
    Game.shared.currentSite = startBase

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("Couldn't save to database. Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

The `Game singleton` is used to store current game properties, such as the `Site` the user is currently located.

After the background task has finished, I want to print `Game.shared.currentSite` (from the main queue). That's what I get:

```
Optional(<Site: 0x17008c080> (entity: Site; id: 0xd000000000100004 <x-coredata://5D8B1335-5F8F-4E66-BC3F-DA7C7AA2B54B/Site/p4> ; data: < fault >))
```

Normally (that's my understanding of CoreData), if you access a `faulted` `NSManagedObject` it fires and loads the data. But here, this doesn't happen.

However, if I run `GameSetupController.setup(withManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)` in the main queue (using the `managedObjectContext` that's declared there) I get this:

```
Optional(<Site: 0x170092610> (entity: Site; id: 0xd000000000140004 <x-coredata://5D8B1335-5F8F-4E66-BC3F-DA7C7AA2B54B/Site/p5> ; data: {
    belongsToPlayer = 1;
    buildings =     (
    );
    coordinates = "0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://5D8B1335-5F8F-4E66-BC3F-DA7C7AA2B54B/Coordinates/p5>";
    events =     (
    );
    name = "Main Base I";
    planet = "0xd000000000140002 <x-coredata://5D8B1335-5F8F-4E66-BC3F-DA7C7AA2B54B/Planet/p5>";
    resources = nil;
    spaceships =     (
    );
}))
```

That's what I want. How can I get this result when using the private managedObjectContext in a background queue? Is it even possible?

Let me know if you need any more code or information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using, `performBackgroundTask` actually

> creates a new NSManagedObjectContext with the concurrencyType set to NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640564-performbackgroundtask?language=objc)

It means that this context will likely get deallocated by the time you print the `Game.shared.currentSite` object. And since it was created inside this no longer existing context, there's no way to un-fault it.

Basically your idea to populate the database in the background thread is good and correct, you just simply have to fetch the `Game.shared.currentSite` object from the main context so that it'll live on while the app is running.

UPDATE:

Also, if you're using `print` method to debug CoreData objects, remember that it won't cause them to un-fault. You can try printing some of their properties instead - that should show you if un-faulting went fine.

Comment: Oh okay. Though I knew it was going to create a new `NSManagedObjectContext`, I thought it would be created as a child of the main `managedObject` from the main queue. That's why I thought it could work. Good to know it doesn't :D. Then I'll have to find a way to tell the `Game singleton` which `Site` it has to fetch. Maybe by using the `ObjectID` of `startBase`?

Comment: Actually this new background context is a child of `viewContext` from AppDelegate's `persistentContainer`. However this doesn't change the fact that it is a different context that gets deallocated. As for the ideas to fetch the `Site` for your `Game` singleton I think using `objectID` property will be the easiest and safest approach.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tried to store the `objectID` to the `Game` singleton (after I saved the context) and then used `managedObjectContext.object(with:)` to retrieve the `currentSite` inside the main queue. But the object it's returning is still a fault. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Try something like this - after `try managedObjectContext.save()` add `Game.shared.currentSite = viewContext.object(with: startBase.objectID) as! Site` where `viewContext` is the context from the `persistentStore` from `AppDelegate`

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood you, in your question you wrote: `in the main queue (using the managedObjectContext that's declared there)`. Is this `managedObjectContext` the `viewContext` from the `persistentStore` or some other context you created?

Comment: Sorry that was indeed misleading. Yes it's the one from the `persistentStore` that's being created in the `appDelegate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136902/discussion-between-user3581248-and-quantm).